# 404 when adding new methods to RESTful web service

Tags: java, rest, glassfish, restful-url

The application works well with the generated methods and classes, but I wanted to get a list of article that matching a specific idChapitre. I get a "HTTP Status 404 - Not Found" on my browser.

This is the facade class, where I have put in the findByIdChapitre method:

```
@Stateless
@Path("articles")
public class ArticleFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Article> {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "PNC-BackendPU")
private EntityManager em;

public ArticleFacadeREST() {
    super(Article.class);
}    
@GET
@Path("bychapitre/{idChapitre}")
@Produces({"application/json"})
public List<Article> findByIdChapitre(@PathParam("idChapitre") Chapitre idChapitre) {
    Query q = em.createNamedQuery("Article.findByIdChapitre");
    q.setParameter("idChapitre", idChapitre);
    return q.getResultList();
}
...
}
```

and my article class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "article")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Article.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Article a"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Article.findByIdArticle", query = "SELECT a FROM Article a WHERE a.idArticle = :idArticle"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Article.findByIdChapitre", query = "SELECT a FROM Article a WHERE a.idChapitre = :idChapitre"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Article.findByCodeArticle", query = "SELECT a FROM Article a WHERE a.codeArticle = :codeArticle")})
public class Article implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id_article", nullable = false)
private Integer idArticle;
@Lob
@Size(max = 65535)
@Column(name = "nom_article", length = 65535)
private String nomArticle;
@Size(max = 20)
@Column(name = "code_article", length = 20)
private String codeArticle;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idArticle")
private List<Littera> litteraList;
@JoinColumn(name = "id_chapitre", referencedColumnName = "id_chapitre", nullable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Chapitre idChapitre;

public Article() {
}

public Article(Integer idArticle) {
    this.idArticle = idArticle;
}

Getters and setters
```

}
 and then my chapitreclass:
    ....

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "chapitre")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Chapitre.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Chapitre c"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Chapitre.findByIdChapitre", query = "SELECT c FROM Chapitre c WHERE c.idChapitre = :idChapitre"),
 @NamedQuery(name = "Chapitre.findByIdSection", query = "SELECT c FROM Chapitre c WHERE c.idSection = :idSection"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Chapitre.findByCodeChapitre", query = "SELECT c FROM Chapitre c WHERE c.codeChapitre = :codeChapitre")})
public class Chapitre implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id_chapitre", nullable = false)
private Integer idChapitre;
@Lob
@Size(max = 65535)
@Column(name = "nom_chapitre", length = 65535)
private String nomChapitre;
@Size(max = 20)
@Column(name = "code_chapitre", length = 20)
private String codeChapitre;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idChapitre")
private List<Dossier> dossierList;
@JoinColumn(name = "id_section", referencedColumnName = "id_section", nullable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Section idSection;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idChapitre")
private List<Article> articleList;

public Chapitre() {
}

public Chapitre(Integer idChapitre) {
    this.idChapitre = idChapitre;
}
Getters and setters
```

}

Comment: What exactly is it you're asking? You need to make your question more clear and provide more information

Comment: I agree, we could use more information, but not necessarily more code, though... :)

Comment: I want to know why my "findByIdChapitre" doesn't work. why it return a 404 error on my browser. is there another configuration to do before that works?

Comment: Have you looked at the server output to see if there are any exceptions, and have you inspected with a logger or with a simple print if the service method is able to read the `Chapitre` instance passed through `@PathParam`? Have you inspected the query result before returning it?

Comment: In the server output nothing appears. When I try to print the chapitre instance I got nothing. And when I try to consume the web service in my output a get "Caused by: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found"

Comment: Everything works well if my parameter is a primitive type I mean String, int, ... but if it's a Chapitre like the case nothing appears even in my output nor with just simple print.